# Scala case class private constructor isn't private

Tags: scala

Today I encountered a strange problem with case class constructors. I wanted to make a constructor private and it seems that it isn't problem. So I've tried it in one of my projects and it works. But in another project I can invoke private constructor and it compiles. I thought it is something with my ide, so I made a standalone class and compile it with scalac. And it compiles. Here is the code:

```
package com.test

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val bar = Bar("12345")
//    bar.doStuff()
    println(bar)
  }
}

case class Bar private(foo: String){
  private def doStuff():Unit = println("stuff")
}
```

The funny thing is that if I uncomment bar.doStuff() it won't compile. So I assume private works in this case, but somehow doesn't work for constructor. What am I doing wrong?
Scalac is 2.11.8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The notation `val bar = Bar("12345")` is shorthand for `val bar = Bar.apply("12345")`, in other words, it calls the `apply` method of the (automatically generated) [companion object](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html) of the case class.

The companion object has access to the private constructor, so that's why it works.

(Why do you want to make the constructor of a case class `private`? That doesn't sound like a good idea).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew about apply method, but somehow didn't think about it here. As for your question I want to have a field that is initialized in apply method and only there.

Comment: @ArtemMalinko it will probably easiest to make it a regular class (with optionally a companion object) so that you have full control over the constructor and the `apply` method. Note that case classes are really just syntactic sugar, you can do everything you need with a regular class just as well (but you'll need to write some things yourself).

Comment: @Jesper Yes, I ended up with the same decision. Thank you.

Comment: Confusing part is that it didn't use to work: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9425  There are tickets around interaction of private ctor and case features like copy.

Comment: `Why do you want to make the constructor of a case class private`. What about when making a "smart constructor", i.e. only define a `class` if it's valid? Example - only make a `Person` if `name` is non-empty and `age` > 0: `case class Person(name: String, age: String)` with `object Person { def build(name: String, age: Int): Option[Person] }`. As you note, using a `case class` provides "reasonable" `hashCode` and `equals` implementations, so it does that work for the developer.

Comment: @KevinMeredith my remark was specifically about making the constructor of a **case class** private, not about why you'd want to make a constructor private in general. Case classes have a specific purpose (as a data transfer object, for pattern matching), and making the constructor of a case class private doesn't fit with this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

If you want `Bar("abc")` to not compile, here's a simple workaround.

Quickly tested in 2.12.3. Doesn't work in 2.11.8

```
case class Bar private (value: String)
object Bar {
  private def apply(v: String) = new Bar(v) // makes the method private
  def create(value: String): Bar = ... // your own implementation
}

val bar = Bar("abc") // compile error
val bar = new Bar("abc") // compile error
val bar = Bar.create("abc") // ok
```